# How to pass dataframe as a parmeter in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

my dataframe contains 10000+ rows , 2 columns
columns are y(val) and its pobability (in decimal)
 i have to apply formula:

```
=[0 if y_score < 0.5 else 1]
ypred=[0 if y_score < 0.5 else 1]
```

and Add column which will show either 0 or 1 as output corresponding to the value.

pls provide the syntax as i am new in python world.

I am trying to pass whole dataframe in calling function but not getting result.

```
def class_label(df):
    if df['proba'] > 0.5:
        df['Class'] == 1
    else:
        df['Class'] == 0  // function def
```

and

```
df['class'] = class_label(df) - calling function
```

Comment: [Here's the syntax](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/function.html)

Comment: `df['proba']` is a series. (which is a list-like or array-like container but different in it's own way) .You need to look at how to work with an array or series of values, Just a simple `if` statement won't do.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do :

```py
def class_label(df):
    df.loc[df['proba']<0.5, 'Class'] = 0
    df.loc[df['proba']>=0.5, 'Class'] = 1
    return df
```

Comment: i am trying to call this function with following code:

Comment: df['Class'] = y_dash(df['proba'])  -  class will be my new variable which will add column named  Class to my dataframe.

I am getting following error:

  1 def y_dash(df):
----> 2     df.loc[df['proba']<0.5, 'label'] = 0
      3     df.loc[df['proba']<0.5, 'label'] = 1
      4     return df


pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: 'proba'

please check

Comment: this just means that you do not have any column named "proba" in your dataframe